# Recarregar tabela sem atualizar toda página? Mvc Applications

Tags: asp.net, mvc

tenho uma aplicação que insiro algumas informações através de uma chamada Ajax, até aqui tudo bem, os dados inserem normalmente porém, eu só consigo visualizar as alteração depois que faço um refresh na pagina, eu queria então que, ao inserir os dados através do Ajax, minha tabela fosse alterada dinamicamente, sem precisar ter que recarregar a pagina. Caso alguém consiga me dar algum exemplo de como fazer isso, ficaria muito grato pela ajuda.

Ajax para inserir dados...

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#Salvar').click(function () {
                var url = "/Candidato/insert";
                var curso = $("#curso").val();
                var instituicao = $("#instituicao").val();
                $.post(url, { curso: curso, instituicao: instituicao }, function (data) {
                    $("index").html(data);
                });
            })
</script>
```

Comment: Precisa serem passadas mais informações. Por exemplo o que é esse objeto `index`, que dados são retornados em `data`, como é constituída essa tabela e talvez o código do servidor que gera essa tabela.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você vai precisar manipular o DOM dinamicamente via JavaScript, imagine que você tem uma tabela, basta apaga-la e reconstruí-la com os novos dados quando o servidor retornar uma resposta. O exemplo que você mostrou não tem a estrutura de dados retornada e nem a tabela, mas digamos que você tenha a seguinte estrutura:

```
<table id="table1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Idade</th>
        </tr> 
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table1Body">
        <tr>
            <td>João</td>
            <td>19</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

E que o servidor retorne a seguinte estrutura de dados que será passada para a variável `response`:

```
{
    "data": [
        0: {
            "name": "Júlio",
            "age": 23
        },
        1: {
            "name": "Ricardo",
            "age": 18
        }
    ]
}
```

Esses dados vem da seguinte chamada ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#Salvar').click(function () {
            var url = "/Candidato/insert";
            var curso = $("#curso").val();
            var instituicao = $("#instituicao").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: { curso: curso, instituicao: instituicao },
                method: 'POST',
                success: (response) => {
                    // Limpa a tabela
                    $("#table1Body").empty();

                    for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                        // Adiciona no corpo da tabela com id #table1Body
                        $("#table1Body").append(
                            '<tr>' +
                            `    <td>${response.data[i].name}</td>` + 
                            `    <td>${response.data[i].age}</td>` +
                            '</tr>'
                        )
                    }
                },
            });
        })
</script>
```

Com jQuery, tudo o que é dinâmico se resume a limpar um elemento e reconstruí-lo com novos dados, a partir daí, você pode tratar exceções e personalizar a resposta para o cliente.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda amigo, deu certo.